# MYSQL Trigger Error,

Tags: php, mysql, triggers, phpmyadmin

I am trying to create a very simple MySQL trigger that will run on the insertion or updating of a row on one table (Screws). I thought I had it pretty close however when I run the query to create the trigger, it just fails and says error, nothing to point me in the right direction.

Here is what I have so far, I am just wanting to take the value of two columns within the table and multiply them and then update the result into a third column, I want this to happen whenever a new record is added or edited within this table. I have tried matching some examples I have seen so far as best I can but nothing seems to quite match.

```
delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER estimate
AFTER INSERT ON `Screws` FOR EACH ROW
begin
UPDATE Screws SET Quantity = Weight * num_per_ounce;
end;
delimiter ;
```

Comment: In your title you write about an Error, what is the error? Does it have a message and/or a number?

Comment: Thanks for the reply hakre, the error had no other information than just "Error". Which is partly why I am posting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to change the same table where you are inserting a row, then don't use an *after* insert trigger.  Instead use a *before* insert trigger:

```
delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER screws_insert
BEFORE INSERT ON `Screws` FOR EACH ROW
begin
    SET new.Quantity = new.Weight * new.num_per_ounce;
end;
delimiter ;
```

You are essentially trying to add a calculated column, which MySQL does not directly support.

If you want a trigger for `update` as well, then you need two triggers:

```
delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER screws_update
BEFORE UPDATE ON `Screws` FOR EACH ROW
begin
    SET new.Quantity = new.Weight * new.num_per_ounce;
end;
delimiter ;
```

Notice I changed the trigger names to include the table.  This is usually a good practice to help keep track of triggers.

Comment: Thank you Gordon, your explanation clears that up pretty well, I will try implementing it shortly. As a side note, its been awhile since I have been on here but where is the upvote button?

Comment: Quick update, I was able to make the first statement work however it appears that MySQL version I have doesn't allow me to have multiple triggers for the same things so I suppose I am limited in that way unless I can set it to run on UPDATE or INSERT which I don't think will work from my quick trial. Perhaps using CHANGE instead of UPDATE or INSERT would lead to the desired behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I will post my eventual solution for anyone else that has a similar issue.

Turns out I forgot to change the Trigger action in the other trigger, so I have both functioning now. Here is my final code, I have added a check to prevent it from running if there is no data input in the two fields it checks.

```
CREATE TRIGGER screws_insert
BEFORE INSERT ON `Screws` FOR EACH ROW
begin
IF new.Weight AND new.num_per_ounce IS NOT NULL THEN
    SET new.Quantity = new.Weight * new.num_per_ounce;
END IF;
end;

CREATE TRIGGER screws_update
BEFORE UPDATE ON `Screws` FOR EACH ROW
begin
IF new.Weight AND new.num_per_ounce IS NOT NULL THEN
    SET new.Quantity = new.Weight * new.num_per_ounce;
END IF;
end;
```

Be sure to set the delimiter to // before running the SQL. 
Thanks to both users who contributed to this solution!